# Finder can‘t connect to iPhone via Wifi (Catalina)

Tags: iphone, mac, finder, catalina

So is seems no matter what I try I can’t get **Finder** on latest Catalina (10.15.4) on MBP 2018 to see my iPhone in **Finder** after initial setup and sync.
I did turn on the `show this iphone when on wifi` option.

All I get is a spinning wheel:

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you force-restarted the iPhone, and safe-booted the MBP?